# 'NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey' undeclared

Tags: iphone, ios5, backup

My iPhone application contains approx 500 MB data. and application will use this data offline. So i mark the folder to do not backup/copy on iTunes. so i am using below url :
https://gist.github.com/1999985

But it says 'NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey' undeclared. and i also tried to used https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html
but i always return false..

So please let me know how it will works??

Thx

Comment: you need iOS 5.1 SDK for this to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` should compile fine on 5.1+ SDK. 
As the key is not available for 5.0, the following snippet could act as a workaround.

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0.1"))
{
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];            
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0); 
    return result == 0;
}          
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.1"))
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    //[URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
    [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey" error:&error];
    return error == nil;
}
```

Comment: I already used this code but my application rejected. I am storing data in documents folder... you have any idea?

Comment: You might have to read the storage guidelines to make sure you picked to right folder for storage. I would not know what kind of data you are saving. May be try `Library/Cache` instead of `Documents` folder. Better explained here http://www.saumitrabhave.com/2011/11/air-ios-solving-apps-must-follow-ios.html

Comment: This code do not work on iOS 5.0 devices! Even if your Base SDK is 5.1, `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` is not weak linked and make your app crash on iOS < 5.1 phone!! If anyone have a solution, i would be glad to know it.

Answer (score 2):

i got a error on use "SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO" to check the OS version, my apps is develop in old OS tools.
so i change to this, replace for "SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO"

```
double currSysVer =[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue];
if (currSysVer>=5.1) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    //[URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
    [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey" error:&error];
    return error == nil;
}else{

    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];            
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0); 
    return result == 0;

}
```